# Library to access Javadoc from Java

Tags: java, javadoc

I want to find a library that I can use from my Java application that will allow me to access specific Javadoc in the scope of my project (I specify where Javadocs are located). Just like in Netbeans, I want to potentially access the Javadoc from html files locally and remotely, and from source.

I expect that I could use code from Netbeans to achieve this, but I don't know how, and I can't easily digest their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Today I started thinking about the same thing.
From CI point of view, I could use @author annotation to send e-mail to someone, who wrote a test that is failing with error, not with a failure.

Google didn't help me (or I didn't google deep enough), so I started wondering how to do it on my own.

First thing that came to my mind is writing a little tool that will check all *.java files specified in a directory, bound file name to annotations and allow user to perform some actions on them.

Is that reasonable?

Comment: I wanted more general access, and I think it will be available in Java 8.